# Where is nose's assert_raises function?

Tags: python, nose

I'm using nose 1.1.2 to write tests for a Python project. There is this `assert_raises` function that happens to be mentioned in the documentation but I can't find it anywhere.

It should be a shorthand for something like this:

```
value_error_raised = False
try:
    do_something_that_should_raise_value_error()
except ValueError:
    value_error_raised = True
assert value_error_raised

type_error_raised = False
try:
    do_something_else_that_should_raise_type_error()
except TypeError:
    type_error_raised = True
assert type_error_raised
```

that would become:

```
assert_raises(ValueError,
              do_something_that_should_raise_value_error)

assert_raises(TypeError,
              do_something_else_that_should_raise_type_error)
```

I already searched the source code and the only mention I found was in the tools.py module, inside the `raises` documentation:

> If you want to test many assertions about exceptions in a single test, you may want to use `assert_raises` instead.

Was this function removed from nose? If so, could someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> from nose.tools import assert_raises
>>> assert_raises
<bound method Dummy.assertRaises of <nose.tools.Dummy testMethod=nop>>
>>> import nose
>>> nose.__version__
'1.1.2'
```

I personally use the unittest2.TestCase classes with nosetests, and use self.assertRaises.

Comment: Ok, that works! Thanks! I just realized that the reason it is not explicitly defined on nose.tools is that because it is a workaround through unittest.TestCase assertRaise implementation. Consequently  eclipse keep reporting a import error on `from nose.tools import assert_raises`.

Comment: it is not just that where PyDev is wrong, in a larger project using Jython I remember having to add exceptions for more than a hundred identifiers...

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`@raises(*exceptions)`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.raises) decorator on your test function.

Comment: That verifies if one of the exceptions was raised, so I would need a test function for each expected error raised. If I want a single test function to verify many exceptions raised, that does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer applies to the reason why you cannot find info about assert_raises.

From [nose documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html):

> The nose.tools module provides […] all of the same assertX methods found in unittest.TestCase (only spelled in PEP 8 fashion, so assert_equal rather than assertEqual)

Here are [PEP 8's suggested function naming](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) and [list of *assertX* methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#assert-methods) in Python's base documentation.